# MYSQL Query Index Check

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

I have a table with the following structure;

```
CREATE TABLE `operations_copy` (
  `id` bigint(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `zoneId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `machineId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `shiftId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `statusId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `actualCycle` float(10,4) NOT NULL,
  `targetCycle` float(10,4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=185538661 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have nearly 200m records in this table.

I am frequently performing the following queries on this table;

#### 1 - Operations By Zone

```
SELECT zoneId, statusId, COUNT(*) as intervals 
FROM `operations` 
WHERE (`date` > 'XXXX-XX-XX' AND `date` <= 'XXXX-XX-XX') 
GROUP BY `zoneId`,`statusId` 
ORDER BY NULL;
```

#### 2 - Operations By Machine

```
SELECT machineId, statusId, COUNT(*) as intervals 
FROM `operations` 
WHERE (`date` > 'XXXX-XX-XX' AND `date` <= 'XXXX-XX-XX') GROUP BY `machineId`,`statusId` 
ORDER BY NULL;
```

#### 3 - Operations By Shift

```
SELECT shiftId, statusId, COUNT(*) as intervals 
FROM `operations` 
WHERE (`date` > 'XXXX-XX-XX' AND `date` <= 'XXXX-XX-XX') 
GROUP BY `shiftId`,`statusId` 
ORDER BY NULL;
```

I am currently looking at 30s for query #1.

I have enabled caching, which reduces the query time dramatically after the initial query, but I still want to optimise the initial query.

Studying has shown me that I need to make better use of indexes (ref: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really, MYSQL docs and more). So I want to check the following indexes will be the best to optimise each query;

```
#1

KEY `operations_by_zone_query` (`date`,`zoneId`,`statusId`,`id`)
```

```
#2

KEY `operations_by_machine_query` (`date`,`machineId`,`statusId`,`id`)
```

```
#3

KEY `operations_by_shift_query` (`date`,`shiftId`,`statusId`,`id`)
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the id is primary key and automatically indexed.

Comment: I’m using the id as a covering index. Not sure if that is correct usage, but I just tested this on a smaller set (3m) of the same records and these indexes above means query #1 takes 2s, removing the id from the index increases query #1 to 17s.

Comment: i wonder why , you don't use it in your query. could you also provide a EXPLAIN with and without the id in the combined index, if you don't mind

Comment: I doubt removing id will change the execution plan and query time because as nbk said it's already included into each index. Also you didn't even use id column in your queries. Could you please provide examples of exact values stored in date column and used in where clause?

Comment: Tacking on `id`, _in this case_, is unnecessary.  It is not in the `SELECT`, so it is not needed for "covering".  InnoDB will silently tack it on, so whether you do or not makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have an interesting idea for you.

Create the following indexes

```
ALTER TABLE operations
    ADD INDEX `date_zoneId_statusId_ndx`    (`date`,`zoneId`,`statusId`)
   ,ADD INDEX `date_machineId_statusId_ndx` (`date`,`machineId`,`statusId`)
   ,ADD INDEX `date_shiftId_statusId_ndx`   (`date`,`shiftId`,`statusId`)
   ,ADD INDEX `zoneId_statusId_date_ndx`    (`zoneId`,`statusId`,`date`)
   ,ADD INDEX `machineId_statusId_date_ndx` (`machineId`,`statusId`,`date`)
   ,ADD INDEX `shiftId_statusId_date_ndx`   (`shiftId`,`statusId`,`date`)
;
```

You could then evaluate your queries by running:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT zoneId, statusId, COUNT(*) as intervals 
FROM `operations` 
WHERE (`date` > 'XXXX-XX-XX' AND `date` <= 'XXXX-XX-XX') 
GROUP BY `zoneId`,`statusId` 
ORDER BY NULL\G

EXPLAIN SELECT machineId, statusId, COUNT(*) as intervals 
FROM `operations` 
WHERE (`date` > 'XXXX-XX-XX' AND `date` <= 'XXXX-XX-XX') GROUP BY `machineId`,`statusId` 
ORDER BY NULL\G

EXPLAIN SELECT shiftId, statusId, COUNT(*) as intervals 
FROM `operations` 
WHERE (`date` > 'XXXX-XX-XX' AND `date` <= 'XXXX-XX-XX') 
GROUP BY `shiftId`,`statusId` 
ORDER BY NULL\G
```

The output from each `EXPLAIN` will plainly tell you which index.

It will also show the least number of steps the Query Optimizer will take.

My guess is that the indexes with the `date` column last will be selected. An exception may be a small date range which may favor the indexes with the `date` column first. In that instance, you would want to keep all 6 indexes.

The indexes with the `date` column last would be used by the `GROUP BY` so that no temp table sorting would be necessary.

***WARNING ON HAVE MANY INDEXES*** : Bulk `INSERT` performance would suffer due to managing multiple covering indexes, but `SELECT` performance would improve greatly. Dropping unnecessary indexes becomes a necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Would you prefer 3 seconds instead of 30?  Or maybe even 0.3, if the planets are aligned right.

Build and maintain a "Summary table".  The perform a similar query against the summary table.  It is likely to be 10 times as fast.  (And you won't need the 3 or 6 indexes on the big table.)  MOre info:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

It *may* be practical to have a single Summary Table:

```
date,   -- not datetime
machineId,
statusId,
shifted,
subtotal,   -- from COUNT(*) for the combo
PRIMARY KEY(one of the needed indexes),
plus the other two indexes needed
```

The summarization could be done every night (necessitating an index *starting with* date in the main table) or done in realtime via a IODKU.  (Performance may dictate one versus the other.)

Side notes:

- `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` is wasteful.  It leads to an extra rounding.  Either go with plain `FLOAT` (4 bytes, but only about 7 significant digits) or plain `DOUBLE` (8 bytes and 16 significant digits or `DECIMAL(10,4)` (5 bytes) or maybe a smaller `DECIMAL`.
- Consider shrinking the ids from 4-byte to something smaller.  This would shrink the table, thereby helping speed slightly.  And it would shrink the tables of machines, shifts, and statuses.  And it would shrink the recommended indexes (that I want you not to add).  And it would help the summary table(s) (that I do want you to add).
- No, I don't know which set of 3 indexes (see Rolando's Answer) is better.
- `date > 'XXXX-XX-XX' AND date <= 'XXXX-XX-XX'` -- Midnight usually belongs with the starting date, not the ending one.  That is, I would expect to see `date >= 'XXXX-XX-XX' AND date < 'XXXX-XX-XX'`